# Does `LoaderManager.restartLoader` create a new object?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, asynctaskloader

Does the `restartLoader(int id, Bundle args, LoaderCallbacks<D> callback)` create an entirely new loader object? Or does it just reuse the old one by resetting its internal state?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass the same `ID` each time you call

```
 restartLoader(int id, Bundle args, LoaderCallbacks<D> callback)
```

it will **REUSE** the same loader object. But if you pass a new `ID` it will create a new `Loader` Object. The way this works as from the documentation check [this quote from the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html#restartLoader(int,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks%3CD%3E)):

> Starts a new or restarts an existing Loader in this manager, registers the callbacks to it, and (if the activity/fragment is currently started) starts loading it. If a loader with the same id has previously been started it will automatically be destroyed when the new loader completes its work. The callback will be delivered before the old loader is destroyed.

But you do not have to dig deep on this because the `ID` is what matters as from this Documentation guide, [check the Loader Summary Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html?):

> To start loading data from a loader, call either initLoader() or restartLoader(). The system automatically determines whether a loader with the same integer ID already exists and will either create a new loader or reuse an existing loader.

So in short if you pass a different `ID` it will create a new loader but if you pass the same `ID` it will use the same loader. But remember `Cursors` are not reused.